# Error in the size when I Encrypt an Object with RSA

Tags: java

I have to Encrypt a message as follows:

```
EB(receiver, “message”)
```

B is the receiver public key. So i made a class called `EncryptionParameter` that contains two `String`s, receiver and the message. After i read the public key of the receiver:

```
EncryptionParameter encryptionParameter = new EncryptionParameter ();
encryptionParameter.setEncrParameter(reciver , message);
// the reciverand the message are both String

// I created  a class to convert an object to byte[]  called ObjectToByte
ObjectToByte otp = new ObjectToByte();
byte[] MByte = otp.convert(encryptionParameter); // convert the object to byte[]
//  Encrypt the message 
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,reciverKey); 
byte[] myEncryptMessage = c.doFinal(MByte);
```

I see an error saying "117bytes limit while encrypting." I tried another way which is

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,senderKey); 
SealedObject myEncryptMessage = new SealedObject( encryptionParameter, c);
```

The same error appeared so is there any way to encrypt an object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help